# got the exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net

I have developed one windows application(C#.net).  I got the exception,

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

stack trace is

> at OnamVideoCable.Bill_Generate.btnBill_Click(Object sender, EventArgs
> e) in
> C:\FinalOnam\CableOperatorSoftware\OnamVideoCable\OnamVideoCable\Bill
> Generate.cs:line 179
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons
> button, Int32 clicks)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr
> hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>
> at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG&
> msg)
>
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
> dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
> reason, ApplicationContext context)
>
> at
> System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
> reason, ApplicationContext context)
>
> at OnamVideoCable.Program.Main() in
> C:\FinalOnam\CableOperatorSoftware\OnamVideoCable\OnamVideoCable\Program.cs:line
> 19
>
> at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[]
> args)
>
> at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>
> at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

code:

```cs
private void btnBill_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int CustNo=0;
    int PayMonth;
    objB.OB = Convert.ToDouble(txtOB.Text);
    
    if (ddCustSelect.Text == "All Customers")
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable dtCustNo = objCust.GetCustInfoForBill();
            foreach (DataRow drCustNo in dtCustNo.Rows)
            {
                 CustNo = Convert.ToInt32(drCustNo["CustNo"]);
                 DataTable dtR = new DataTable();
                    dtR=objR.GetLastReceiptInfo(CustNo);
                if (dtR != null)
                {
                    if (dtR.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow drR = dtR.Rows[0];
                        //groupBox1.Visible = true;
                        //lblReceipt.Text = Convert.ToString(drR["RNo"]);
                        //lblPaidAmt.Text = Convert.ToString(drR["Amount"]);
                        // lbloutstand.Text = Convert.ToString(drR["Balance"]);
                        //lblMonthRate.Text = Convert.ToString(drR["MonthlyRate"]);
                        DateTime paydate = Convert.ToDateTime(drR["date"]);
                        //lblPayMonth.Text = Convert.ToString(drR["paydate"]);
                        PayMonth = paydate.Month;
                        objB.LastOut = Convert.ToDouble(drR["Balance"]);
                        total = calculate_bill(PayMonth, ddMonth.SelectedIndex + 1, Convert.ToDouble(drR["Balance"]), Convert.ToDouble(drR["MonthlyRate"]));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PayMonth = ddMonth.SelectedIndex + 1;
                        DataTable dtRate = objRate.GetExistCustRate(CustNo);
                        DataRow drRate = dtRate.Rows[0];
                        //total = calculate_bill(PayMonth, ddMonth.SelectedIndex + 1, 0, Convert.ToDouble(drRate["Total"]));
                        //objB.LastOut = 0;
                        total = Convert.ToDouble(drRate["Total"]);
                        objB.LastOut = total;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    PayMonth = ddMonth.SelectedIndex + 1;
                    DataTable dtRate = objRate.GetExistCustRate(CustNo);
                    DataRow drRate = dtRate.Rows[0];
                    //total = calculate_bill(PayMonth, ddMonth.SelectedIndex + 1, 0, Convert.ToDouble(drRate["Total"]));
                    //objB.LastOut = 0;
                    total = Convert.ToDouble(drRate["Total"]);
                    objB.LastOut = total;
                    //MessageBox.Show("Table is null");
                }
                objB.CustNo = Convert.ToInt32(CustNo);
                objB.Month = ddMonth.Text;
                objB.Year = ddYear.Text;
                objB.Total = total;

                DataTable dtBill = new DataTable(); 
                   dtBill = objB.checkBill();
                   if (dtBill != null)
                   {
                       if (dtBill.Rows.Count > 0)
                       {
                           // MessageBox.Show("Bill is Already Generated");
                           continue;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           objB.GenerateBill();

                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       //MessageBox.Show("2nd table is null");
                       objB.GenerateBill();
                   }
               
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Bill is generated");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + CustNo);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
    if (ddCustSelect.Text == "Single Customer")
    {
        try
        {
            //panelSingle.Visible = true;
            // groupBox1.Visible = true;
            objB.CustNo = Convert.ToInt32(ddCustNo.Text);
            objB.Month = ddMonth.Text;
            objB.Year = ddYear.Text;
            objB.Total = Convert.ToDouble(lblTotalBill.Text);
            if (lbloutstand.Visible)
            {
                objB.LastOut = Convert.ToDouble(lbloutstand.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                objB.LastOut = objB.Total;
            }
           
            DataTable dtBill = objB.checkBill();
            if (dtBill != null)
            {
                if (dtBill.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Bill is Already Generated");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (objB.GenerateBill())
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Bill is generated..");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error while generating bill");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("2nd table null");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
        }

        
    }
}//----this is line no 179
```

Comment: something is null when you are accessing it

Comment: Please show us the code for btnBill_Click.

Comment: Which object throws the exception? try initializing that particular object.

Answer (score 1):

So look carefully at (or near - the numbers can be a few out) line 179 in

> at OnamVideoCable.Bill_Generate.btnBill_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\FinalOnam\CableOperatorSoftware\OnamVideoCable\OnamVideoCable\Bill Generate.cs:line 179

Something in there is null. Add a breakpoint and use the debugger. Either check for the null, or fix whatever is making it null unexpectedly. I can't tell you what - I can't see your code!

Comment: @sonal and which is line 179?

Comment: closing curly brace of private void btnBill_Click()

Comment: @sonal then (seeing also your comment about the debugger) you're going to need to break this method down a bit (refactor it into methods) and add logging / some kind of "what was I doing when I blew up" info. We can't debug it for you. Have fun.

Comment: can you please elaborate it?i have more than 300 custno so it is taking much time to complete foreach loop.

Comment: @sonal "elaborate"? Sure: one of those lines is doing something that is getting a null, and not coping with that. Only you can find out which. We aren't psychic. Debug it. That doesn't always mean "with a debugger". This is a fundamental part of your job, so... Go do that.

Answer (score 0):

look at Generate.cs:line 179, check the variables you use in this line, one of them is null

Comment: while debugging the project i didn't get the exception.

Comment: closing curly brace of private void btnBill_Click()